# Image Boxes Alignment

Tags: html, css, image, block

I'm having some problems with alignment of image boxes as they are not properly aligned although they are using the same css class. The middle box is a few pixels above then other. Here is the link to specific problem.

http://www.homemadetools.net/forum/few-bits-pces-135#post338

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the image width and height. Its is to show the correct place withe correct width and height propery.

```
ima.class_name {
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
border: 5px solid red;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is with the container boxes which are not aligned, the pears equal in height & width but the right & left boxes are a few pixels below the middle box.

Comment: set the all images width and height.